# Changing the background to a picture based on an <option> value selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know this question was, very similarly asked before, however I did not find the answer in that feed as the answer did not work with my other JavaScript.
Here's my problem. I am trying to add in a menu to change the background on a form I am working on. I cannot figure out how to make the background change to an image when an `<option>` is selected from the `<select>` field. I would like to accomplish this with just JavaScript, but I will use JQuery if need be.

```
<label for="pictype">Select a New Background</label>
<select id="pictype" name="pictype" onclick="picchange()">
    <option value="p1">pic1</option>
    <option value="p2">pic2</option>
    <option value="p3">pic3</option>
    <option value="p4">pic4</option>
    <option value="p5">pic5</option>
    <option value="p6">pic6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You forgot to post your picchange() function.

Comment: Thanks every one! Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a .change event, and smart file naming to achieve this result. Using jQuery is by far the easiest solution.

If you name your images the same as the option values, you can then reference images based off of the current option selected. So for the first option you could name the picture, p1.jpg.

```
<label for="pictype">Select a New Background</label>
    <select id="pictype" name="pictype">
    <option value="p1">pic1</option>
    <option value="p2">pic2</option>
    <option value="p3">pic3</option>
    <option value="p4">pic4</option>
    <option value="p5">pic5</option>
    <option value="p6">pic6</option>
    </select>
```

#### jQuery

```
 $("#pictype").change(function(){
    var imageFileName = $(this).val();
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(../Images/"+imageFileName+".jpg)");    
});
```

So if you selected option #1, it would set the background image url to url("../Images/p1.jpg");

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtruty/3L2uP/
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
    $( "#pictype" ).change(function(){

        if( this.value == "p1" ) //here goes code to change picture
        if( this.value == "p2" ) //here goes code to change picture
        ......

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qwnm6/

```
<label for="pictype">Select a New Background</label>
<select id="pictype" name="pictype" onchange="document.body.style.background = this.value">
    <option value="red">pic1</option>
    <option value="green">pic2</option>
    <option value="blue">pic3</option>
    <option value="yellow">pic4</option>
    <option value="lime">pic5</option>
    <option value="gray">pic6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. NOTE: I deleted your onclick function calling pictype

**HTML**

```
    <select id="pictype" name="pictype">
        <option value="p1">pic1</option>
        <option value="p2">pic2</option>
        <option value="p3">pic3</option>
        <option value="p4">pic4</option>
        <option value="p5">pic5</option>
        <option value="p6">pic6</option>
    </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var selectEl = document.getElementById("pictype");

selectEl.onclick = function () {

    if (this.value == "p1") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "Black";
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "White";
    }
}
```